# undefined method `original_filename' for "download.png":String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file, methods, upload, undefined

I read the similar questions, but it was not my case I think.

My view:

```
    = form_for [:test, @new], :remote => true do |f|
= f.label :title, 'title'
= f.text_field :title, :class => :span6

    = label :news, :image_preview, 'Изображение'
= file_field :news, :image_preview, :class => 'btn'
```

My controller:

```
def create

  uploaded_io = params[:news][:image_preview]
  File.open(Rails.root.join('public', 'uploads', uploaded_io.original_filename), 'w') do |file|
    file.write(uploaded_io.read)
  end 

end
```

Uploading file I get this error:

```
undefined method `original_filename' for "download.png":String
```

Comment: put the tags for the language and topic your question is related to

Comment: are you using paperclip?

Comment: You are missing `:multipart => true` in the form_for line, and `:remote => true` is for javascript. Perhaps you should watch one of the railscasts episodes on paperclip or carrierwave, or buy a book on Rails.

Comment: I think no) At least I don't see it in my Gemfile. It is not my code and not my project. And I am nre in RoR)

Comment: Does form_for helper need ":multipart => true"? Are you sure?

Comment: Rails should know to add the `multipart` stuff automatically if the form includes a file_field (unless you're on a really old Rails version). In your development log, what does the post data look like? (it'll start something like "Started POST "/news"...")